# Need a listbox of drop-down commands

Tags: winforms, controls

In WinForms, I have to quickly set up a list of items that have some text and a dropdown of commands/buttons.  This would be easy in XAML (I'm getting spoiled), but I'm not familiar with Winforms.

Do any of the std Winform controls provide this?
  Can anyone suggest a 3rd party control??

The image shows a drop-down being shown when hovered.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a normal context menu, so you can probably do this with the [`ContextMenuStrip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx) component. Call one of its [`Show()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.show.aspx) methods when you want to open it.

Comment: Thanks.  These need to be in some sort of list container.  Can I associate a right-click with a ListBox item??

Comment: Maybe. But if you have a drop-down arrow, it's not a normal `ListBox` item, is it? Probably you can put drop-down lists in the `ListBox` somehow, hook up a handler to their drop-down event, and show the menu from that handler. Since I don't have VS handy right now, this is a bit of guesswork, sorry

Comment: Just set the ListBox.ContextMenuStrip property.  You can do so in the designer.  ListView works too.

Comment: Hans - is there any way to tell which listbox item was right-clicked?